# mojjara JSF 2.0 vs myfaces behaving differently

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, myfaces

I am working on web application upgrade which involves below two upgrades

JSF 1.0 -> 2.x , 
Webspehere 7.0 -> 8.5

After upgrade if I switch to  myfaces libs provided in WAS8.5 plugins, certain elements in UI tend to break. If I keep the implementaion to mojjara JSF2.0 libs, it seems to work fine.

One of the errors I am getting when I use myFaces 2.0 is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component javax.faces.component.UIInput is no javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText
```

This happened because `<inputText>` which is of type `javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText` tag had a binding to a model which returned `new UIInput();` in `getter` method of `model`. (I know this is a bad code. But it's existing and was written to initialize text field with default values)

I can understand why this should not work. Because `HtmlInputText` is a subClass of `UIInput`. And when we try to bind object of `Parent` class where `Child` class is expected, this error is thrown. This is similar to when we try to cast a Parent Object to Child reference

Now if this is the case, then my question is how same code works with Mojjara JSF implementation. If I switch to Mojjara, I don't face this issue, which is surprising. Because I expected this issue with this also, since code violates general Parent Child Class rules.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page - [JavaServer Faces migration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_jsfmigrate.html?lang=en) - it describes some migration details. In particular, if you use JWL:

> You must update widget library to version 3.1.6 or higher to enable
>   compatibility with the changes in the JSF 2.0 implementation. Obtain a
>   compatible version of JWL by upgrading IBM® Rational® Application
>   Developer for WebSphere to 7.5.5.2 or later or installing IBM Rational
>   Application Developer for WebSphere V8.0 and later.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I checked and JWL used is updated one.

Comment: One of the errors I am getting is --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component javax.faces.component.UIInput is no javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText

Comment: @Amit.rk3 Did you try to switch JSF configuration to Sun RI via console?

Comment: But sun RI configuration is JSF 1.2 right ? while my requirement is to upgrade it to JSF2.0

Comment: it works fine with JSF 2.0 Mojjara. I just want to avoid adding additional mojjarra libs in the webapp and force loading them by setting classloader to parent_last

Comment: @Amit.rk3 I was just suggesting to test both configurations as described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-13-2-33-0-2-3&lang=en) before adding your own into application.

Comment: I did some analysis and found out that **inputText** tag has binding which evaluates to **javax.faces.component.UIInput** class , but it's expecting it to be of type **javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText** . If I change the binding type to javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText , it's working. But now problem is there are hundreds of tags in the application which are bound to javax.faces.component.UIInput

Comment: Updated the question. I got the resolution to fix my UI. But now I am not able to understand why this works in Mojjara